# Implement re.search() functionality in Groovy or Java

Tags: java, groovy

I need a Groovy/Java function to search for groups in a string based on regular expression

Ex:

`function("([\w-]+)-([\w.-]+)\.([\w.-]+)" ,"commons-collections-3.2.2.jar" )`

should return a list `["commons-collections" , "3.2.2" , "jar"]`

Python can do this by

```
>> import re

>> re.search("([\w-]+)-([\w.-]+)\.([\w.-]+)" ,"commons-collections-3.2.2.jar" )

>> print(result.groups())
```

output is `("commons-collections" , "3.2.2" , "jar")`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? Please update your question with the code you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a simple and basic task in groovy. Any way I hope this answer will help you.

```
"commons-collections-3.2.2.jar".findAll(/([\w-]+)-([\w.-]+)\.([\w.-]+)/) {    
    println it 
}
```

This will produce the output :

```
[commons-collections-3.2.2.jar, commons-collections, 3.2.2, jar]
```

**Update :**

As @tim_yates mentioned in comment,

```
println "commons-collections-3.2.2.jar".findAll(/([\w-]+)-([\w.-]+)\.([\w.-]+)/) { it.tail() }
```

This provides better output than above and also more specific to the task.

Output:

```
[[commons-collections, 3.2.2, jar]]
```

Comment: A better (?) solution would be: `def result = "commons-collections-3.2.2.jar".findAll(/([\w-]+)-([\w.-]+)\.([\w.-]+)/) { it.tail() }` which will return the three fields required in the question

Comment: @tim_yates Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated my answer accordingly.